# Bind to property attached to content created by DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a MVVM application with `Window` that should display content based on the child view model. I use `ContentControl` and data templates and this works fine:

### DialogWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ContentControlApplication.DialogWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContentControlApplication"
  Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestViewModel}" >
      <local:TestControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding SubViewModel}" x:Name="myPresenter" />
</Window>
```

### DialogWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class DialogWindow : Window
{
    public DialogWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

### MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public object SubViewModel
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SubViewModel = new TestViewModel();
    }
}
```

### TestViewModel.cs

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string TestProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        TestProperty = "_TEST_";
    }
}
```

### TestControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContentControlApplication.TestControl"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContentControlApplication">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TestProperty}" FontSize="20" Margin="10" Width="100" Height="30" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now I would like to specify the `Window` title in the child view, so I registered attached property in `DialogWindow` code-behind

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DialogTitleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
  "DialogTitle",
  typeof(string),
  typeof(DialogWindow));

public static void SetDialogTitle(UIElement element, string value)
{
    element.SetValue(DialogTitleProperty, value);
}

public static string GetDialogTitle(UIElement element)
{
    return (string)element.GetValue(DialogTitleProperty);
}
```

and applied it to the child view

```
<UserControl ...             
  local:DialogWindow.DialogTitle="My Title">
  ...
</UserControl>
```

and tried to bind the `Window.Title`

```
<Window ....
  Title='{Binding Path=Content.(local:DialogWindow.DialogTitle), ElementName="myPresenter"}'>
  ...
</Window>
```

But it does not work, since the content of the `ContentControl` is the view model itself and not the corresponding view as defined by the DataTemplate.

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in PresentationFramework.dll System.Windows.Data Error: 17 : Cannot get 'DialogTitle' value (type 'String') from 'Content' (type 'TestViewModel'). BindingExpression:Path=Content.(0); DataItem='ContentControl' (Name='myPresenter'); target element is 'DialogWindow' (Name=''); target property is 'Title' (type 'String') InvalidCastException:'System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from ContentControlApplication.TestViewModel to System.Windows.DependencyObject.'

How can I bind to the property attached to the view that is created on-the-fly from the data template?

---

Edited: Renamed `MainWindow` to `DialogWindow` to clear the example intent, corrected name of the attached property member field to follow guidelines.

Comment: As naming convention it should be DialogTitleProperty not DialogTitle

Comment: Your approach looks odd. Besides that your UserControl should not deal with a property that is declared in the MainWindow class, you shouldn't use an attached property for this at all. Why not simple declare a title property on the view model?

Comment: @Clemens I don't want the title to be the property of a view model because I believe the title is a GUI element and as such it should be part of the view declared in XAML (e.g. to allow localization, separation of coders/designers etc). Why shouldn't I use the attached property for this? When a control is placed inside `DockPanel`, I use `DockPanel.Dock` attached property so when a control is placed inside a dialog Window control, I would naturally use its `DialogTitle` attached property, right?

Comment: Maybe, but you wouldn't declare that property in your MainWindow class. How about reusing your UserControls in a different application with another MainWindow?

Comment: @Clemens It's only example. I fixed the question and renamed the `MainWindow` to something else, in general it's not the main window of the application. What I am trying to accomplish is basically to have a generic `DialogWindow` with method `ShowModal(object viewModel)`. It will show dialog window with content according to the passed view model type. I want to declare the dialog's title in the view linked with the view model rather than having the title property in the view model itself.